Embedding Image Texture in Spot Light
Please, walk with me.
I want to use an image to cast shadows in a room.
I put a circle in front of a spot light and using Image Texture node, I  added the image to the circle.
But there's no way I could hide the circle such that the shadows would retain but the circle itself wouldn't show in the camera view.....unless I put image itself inside the light.
It works well with an Area Light. 
But not with the Spot Light.
Is the Spot Light just built different, or did I miss a crucial step?
